# Models na estrutura de MVC são somente para operações com banco de dados?

Tags: php, mvc, engenharia-de-software

Eu aprendi que *"Sempre que você pensar em manipulação de dados, pense em model. Ele é responsável pela leitura e escrita de dados, e também de suas validações."*

Mais tarde uma outra pessoa me disse que models é exclusivamente para tratamento de dados mais especificamente interface de banco de dados, conexão com servidor (ou com outros), update, insert, delete, select e essas coisas referentes a banco de dados.

Nesse caso se eu tiver uma classe chamada **getAllPageContents** responsável por:

- Fazer download de uma determinada pagina na web.
- Extrair todas as metatags desta pagina
- Extrair todos os links e os textos desta pagina

E que retorne em um formato de array. Se eu quiser fazer desta classe um model do meu MVC eu não poderia? Uma vez que não esta relacionado com operações em banco de dados?

No meu caso esta mesma pessoa me recomendou que esta logica da classe acima deveria estar dentro do próprio controller ou em um arquivo separado mas não sendo considerado como um model e fora da pasta model.

Gostaria de saber se esta informação de que os arquivos dentro da pasta model são exclusivos somente para operações com banco de dados é verdadeira, e se for ela é um design pattern?

Comment: Para os exemplos que você deu, geralmente se faz uso desses arquivos como `components`, assim você não vincula à regra de negócio. O `model` não se limita apenas ao BD, você pode ter um modelo para geração de *log* numa tabela do BD e em determinado momento você opta por criar um *TXT*, mas toda a regra de criação para o *log* ainda será no `model`. - **explicando superficialmente**

Answer (score 1):

#### Models se referem a regras de negócio

A camada de Model se refere a qualquer coisa referente as regras de negócio da aplicação, ou seja, ela não se limita a banco de dados.

Se os itens que você listou fazem parte das regras que definem o funcionamento do seu projeto, então eles são pertencentes a camada de Model. Não é necessário se limitar, pois essa camada pode conter validações, leitura de dados de arquivos e etc.